# Snowflake - Storing Column Business name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I export and store column business name on snowflake ? Eg: "LOAN REPAYMENT METHOD CODE" would be the business friendly name for column "LOAN_RPYMT_MTHD_CD" . I can very well start my column comments with the business name Eg: *"LOAN REPAYMENT METHOD CODE - The method by which loan will be repaid . Lumpsum, installments etc.. "* so that it shows up in the COMMENT property.
However I am wondering is there a "dedicated" property in a snowflake table where I can export this to from my data modeling tool (powerdesigner) so that it shows up in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [COMMENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/comment.html) property to store this data, and then retrieve it from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view or use

Example of adding comments to a column:

```sql
alter table t1 alter LOAN_RPYMT_MTHD_CD comment 'LOAN REPAYMENT METHOD CODE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add comments to your column names as description, this will show up in information_schema.columns.

```
create table temp.some_loan_table
(
LOAN_RPYMT_MTHD_CD varchar(200) 
);


ALTER TABLE TEMP.some_loan_table modify
LOAN_RPYMT_MTHD_CD COMMENT 'LOAN REPAYMENT METHOD CODE - The method by which loan will be repaid . Lumpsum, installments etc.. '

SELECT COMMENT FROM DBNAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA."COLUMNS"
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'DBNAME' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TEMP' AND TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_LOAN_TABLE'
```

Comment: Thank you Michael and Jay. As stated in my original post, I very well understand that I could very well add this to COMMENTS. However wondering if there was another "dedicated property" into which I can dump the business name into?

Comment: if you are tyring to track sensitive columns for compliance, discovery, protection, and resource usage use cases .. you can use  tags                                                                   `create tag loan_tag
allowed_values 'loan repayment';

alter table temp.some_loan_table 
modify column loan_rpymt_mthd_cd 
set tag loan_tag = 'loan repayment'

select system$get_tag('loan_tag','dbname.temp.some_loan_table.loan_rpymt_mthd_cd','column'); `

Comment: Thank you Jay. Actually tagging would be the last phase of the activity, exactly as you mentioned, to group the column as sensitive/PII. But to identify, the automated program has to scan the columns and detect if it falls under the PII policy. The current program can't detect patterns like B_DT as BIRTH DATE. So the initial ask from development is to add a property which could store the BIRTH DATE next to B_DT

Comment: Ideally comments should do the trick, however for a specific requirements as yours with an external automated program making decision based on column headings/attributes, you can always go with your own custom solution/table to store column attributes.